# how to translate c header file to delphi 2006

Tags: delphi

How to translate the following?

1)

```
#ifndef __LVR_NET_SDK_H__
#define __LVR_NET_SDK_H__

#ifdef __LVR_NET_EXPORT__
#define LVR_NET_API  extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LVR_NET_API  extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

2)

```
typedef struct {
 DWORD dwAlarmInput;   
         DWORD dwVideoLoss;   
         DWORD dwMotionDetect;  
 DWORD dwVideoCover;  
 DWORD dwReserve[16];  
}LVR_NET_ALARM_INFO, *LPLVR_NET_ALARM_INFO;
```

3)

```
LVR_NET_API DWORD __stdcall LvrNetGetSdkVersion();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

(1):
Depends on if you only want to use this header to interface to the C lib, in that case you can safely ignore it.

(If you are translating a whole package to Delphi, and want to generate a DLL based on it, you'll need to add

something like {$ifdef  LVR_NET_EXPORT} export; {$endif} to the function declarations, and in the main library file (the one that starts with "library") add the function to the "exports" clause (again {$ifdef LVR_NET_EXPORT})
)

In short: ignore

(2):

```
  Type LPLVR_NET_ALARM_INFO = ^LVR_NET_ALARM_INFO
       LVR_NET_ALARM_INFO  = Record
                               dwAlarmInput,
                               dwVideoLoss,
                               dwMotionDetect,
                               dwVideoCover    : DWORD;
                               dwReserve       : array[0..15] of DWord;
                             end;   
       TLVR_NET_ALARM_INFO = LVR_NET_ALARM_INFO; // not needed but Delphi style convention
```

This isn't necessarily enough, since the way the record is packed is not defined this way. But the original fragment also lacks information about packing.

3)

```
  function LvrNetGetSdkVersion:DWord;
```

or

```
  function LvrNetGetSdkVersion:DWord; stdcall; external 'dllname.dll' name 'LvrNetGetSdkVersion';
```

to import from a dll. Note the "name" part where you can adjust the case of the imported identifier

Answer (score 0):

You could translate the structure like this:

```
type
  TLVR_NET_ALARM_INFO = record
    dwAlarmInput : Cardinal;
    dwMotionDetect : Cardinal;
    dwVideoCover : Cardinal;
    dwReserve array [0..15] of Cardinal;
  end;

var
  LVR_NET_ALARM_INFO :  TLVR_NET_ALARM_INFO;
```

and the function declaration:

```
interface

    function LvrNetGetSDKVersion: Cardinal; stdcall;

implementation

    function LvrNetGetSDKVersion; external 'nameofthedll.dll';
```

Everything untested though. I hope it helps

Also check out [DrBob](http://www.drbob42.com/delphi/headconv.htm). There you can find the tool HeadConv which can automatically convert C-Header files to Delphi. Its nice to start with, but not perfect.